# Emulate jQuery's clone() in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, clone

Hi guys its my 1st time here i have spent so many hours actually just to find out how i can do it.

Jquery clone can easily do it for me but the downside is that i can not use it for SEO purpose s.

So i want an alternative by using PHP to copy text inside a tag and echo it anywhere.

```
<div class="content-to-copy" id="content-to-copy">Copy this text</div>
<div class="content-new-location" class="content-new-location"></div>
```

I can easily acheive the above by using jquery clone by using the codes below

[jquery clone code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EDzCi)

How can I do it using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, (simple html dom parser is good actually), you could use `DOMDocument` in conjunction with `DOMXpath` on this one. Consider this example:

```
$original_html = '<div class="content-to-copy" id="content-to-copy">Copy this text</div><div id="content-new-location" class="content-new-location"></div>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($original_html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

// clone
$clone = $xpath->query('//div[@id="content-to-copy"]//text()');
$clone_value = (string) $clone->item(0)->nodeValue;
$xpath->query('//div[@id="content-new-location"]')->item(0)->nodeValue = $clone_value;
// extra styling to see difference
$xpath->query('//div[@id="content-new-location"]')->item(0)->setAttribute('style', 'color: red; font-weight: bold;');

$final_html = $dom->saveHTML($dom);

echo $final_html;
```

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/DhIOhH)